# how to assign an array element in a indexPath from selected cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, didselectrowatindexpath

I have an array with sound list

```
NSArray *nameSound = @[@"alarm-1.wav",@"alarm-2.mp3",@"alarm-3.mp3",@"alarm-4.mp3",@"alarm-5.mp3"];
```

And I have **TableView** with 5 cells,

[image]

How award for indexPath from TableView to element from nameSound

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: Check this: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

Comment: Are you having five different cell?? Or five different rows?

Comment: I assignment to create  [alarm clock](http://www.solveyourtech.com/create-iphone-alarm-goes-everyday/), 
I want to be able to select the sound

Comment: you need to check my answer where you get cell selected method and from there you can get sound name.

Comment: have you googled [uitableview](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=uitableview+with+storyboard+in+objective+c) before posting ques here.

Comment: You don't need static content in your table view. You can create just one prototype cell and reuse it like in Dhanesh's example.

Comment: Thanks to All and sorry, I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       NSString *selectedVal = [nameSound objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       // You can use this selectedVal 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass that array in `tableview`  with the help of  below methods

```
//pass your array count for cell numbers
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [nameSound count];
}

//For Cell creation
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [nameSound objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

//Did Select row will get in below method
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *selectedSound = [nameSound objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
}
```

it will help you to bind `nameSound` data with table cell.